# What do the 6 points stand for in Polygon().getPoints().setAll?

Tags: java, 2d

I have the following code to create a polygon:

```
Polygon poly = new Polygon();
poly.getPoints().setAll(14d, 17d, 26d, 17d, 20d, 27d); // What do these mean?
```

What do these 6 points stand for?

Comment: How many points are there in a triangle? **3**. How many components per-vertex in 2D space? **2**. What is 3 * 2? **6**. The minimum number of components necessary to describe a triangle in 2D space is therefore 6, low and behold that is exactly what you see here. That said, using double-precision components for your vertices is ridiculous. Many people who learn Java are taught that you need double-precision (this is what the `d` suffix means) for everything when you actually need it for almost nothing; fixed-point would be better suited for many applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers define a triangle:

[image]

Giving the x and y coordinates in order like `((X,Y),(X,Y),(X,Y))`.

Might be easier to understand if you wrote the code like this:

```
poly.getPoints().setAll(
  14d, 17d, 
  26d, 17d,
  20d, 27d);
```

When in doubt you can always check [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/shape/Polygon.html).

> Creates a polygon, defined by an array of x,y coordinates.